# What is the difference between fixed effect and random effect model of ANOVA and when these should apply?

Tags: anova, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

ANOVA Test is used on mean score of individual studies' parametric estimates with fixed and Known population or random unknown population.

Comment: As you see in the right sidebar, there are several discussions adressing this question.

Comment: @stephane Laurent what are the assumptions , when and why these should be applied ?explain.

Comment: Have you visited the links I'm talking about ? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode?rq=1 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/what-is-a-difference-between-random-effects-fixed-effects-and-marginal-model?rq=1 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26230/what-is-the-mathematical-difference-between-random-and-fixed-effects?rq=1

Comment: "What is the difference between fixed effect, random effect and mixed effect models?" does not handle ANOVA and therefore is not helpful.