# Context in which an AR(1) error term can be considered a random effect?

Tags: random-effects-model, autoregressive

We have the following situation:
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= f(x_t)+u_t, \\
u_t &= au_{t-1}+\epsilon_t, \\
\epsilon_t &\overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,\sigma^2).
\end{aligned}
To make it simple, let's assume $f$ is deterministic or known.

I think we can see this as a random-effect model, since
$y_t\mid u_{t-1}\sim N(f(x_t)+au_{t-1},\sigma^2)$ and $u_{t-1}$ is randomly distributed (see [this CV stackexchange answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26230/what-is-the-mathematical-difference-between-random-and-fixed-effects)).

Am I right? If not, when could we consider it to be a random effect?

Comment: I have changed the formatting for better visibility, but feel free to undo the change if you do not like it.

Comment: @RichardHardy thanks ;)