# Analysis of binomial variables with random effects

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, inference, repeated-measures, binomial-distribution

I have a study where each of the 43 items is a question to which the response may be A or B and I want to infer whether A has been chosen significantly more than B. There are 20 participants and 43 items, I have thus 20*43= 860 rows in my datafile. I know I can run a binomial test/chi square, but my problem is that these tests don't take into account the unmeasured correlation between responses due to participants and questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mixed effects model, a logistic regression with random intercepts for question and for participant. If you have data in long format, something like

```
participant  question answer
1            1        A
1            2        B
 .
 .
 .
n            1        A
n            2        A
```

the logistic regression will have a linear predictor
$$ \eta_{ij} = \mu + \alpha_i + \beta_j $$
where $\alpha_i$ is a random intercept for participant $i$ and $\beta_j$ a random intercept for question $j$. Then the model is completed by stipulating that
$$
   \alpha_i \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_\alpha) \\ 
   \beta_j \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_\beta)
$$

If you have some other covariates you can build from here.

In R something like

```r
df <- <your data frame>
library(lme4)
mod0 <- glmer( answer ~ (1 | participant) + (1 | question), 
               data=df, family=binomial )
```

This is similar to the setting in item response theory, so look through [item-response-theory](/questions/tagged/item-response-theory).  See also the tag [elo](/questions/tagged/elo), since such rating systems are based on similar models. An interesting applications is the [chess puzzles on lichess](https://lichess.org/training) where both solver and quizz will get its own random parameter (but they will be updated according to how the puzzle is solved).

Comment: Not very familiar to R (python user...) and had a curiosity. "(1 | participant)" is kind like of a one hot encoding where you add n_participants dummy features ? Actually I have also an other question. $\alpha_i$ is the "trait" discussed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item_response_theory ? Can we interpret it as the intelligence of the student ?

Comment: @Thomas: That notation means *a random intercept for each participant* and a typical implementation migfht represent it like you say (bur in R package `lme4` it uses sparse matrices, which is part of the reason for its speed). But the estimation is still different, since it is taken as a random not fixed effect. If you can interpret $\alpha_i$ is intelligence I am sure will be debated, and depend on context and subject matter knowledge not statistics. It might certainly be influenced also by experience, knowledge, industriousness, seriousness of study, ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have a reference/link that explains the difference between a "random intercept" and just a "fixed, but student dependent, intercept" ? Admittedly, I am not appreciating the difference right now and I am curious to know more ...

Comment: @Thomas: I updated my answer to include more details. Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26230/what-is-the-mathematical-difference-between-random-and-fixed-effects  and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode