# Difference between random effect and random intercept model

Tags: stata, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I am looking at clustered data and because I was trained in economics I tend to look at fixed effects and random effects as solutions. An alternative would clearly be multi-level modelling. However, for me the clustering is just a nuisance, so I only care about "controlling it out".

However, looking at the equation of a random intercept model, I cannot see the difference to my random effect model. So I was wondering whether there just might be different names for the same thing, due to differences between disciplines? But then why can you (in Stata) estimate them differently?

- RIM: `xtreg y x, i(id) mle`
- RE: `xtreg y x, re`

However, the equation for both seems to be:

$$y_{ij}= b_{0} + b_{1}x1_{ij}+ u_{j} + e_{ij}$$

(Don't know how to format it nicely, but Google gives examples of RE and RIM equations, which look the same to me easily:

- RE: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_effects_model
- RIM: http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/videos/random-intercepts.html

Comment: Since an intercept is sort of an effect, a random intercept model is a special case of a random effect model. But you are right, there are many different terms for the same methodology.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it is a special case or give me a reference? When I google I only find descriptions of either, but so far no comparison. All I read on RIM could (in my opinion) also be said about RE and vice versa. For example in RIM the group intercepts are the overall intercept+ the cluster error, but RE also has an overall intercept and cluster error?

Comment: E.g. I wouldn't call a random effects model with random slopes a random intercept model. I don't know a reference of my first comment though.

Comment: It is worth explicitly pointing out here that these terms vary importantly & confusingly across disciplines (eg econometrics vs biostatistics). See here: [What is a difference between random effects-, fixed effects-, and marginal model?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21760/7290), & here: [Concepts behind fixed/random effects models](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33984/7290).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A random intercept model estimates separate *intercepts* for each unit of each level at which the intercept is permitted to vary. This is one kind of random effect model. Another kind of random effect model also includes *random slopes*, and estimates separate slopes (i.e. coefficients, betas, effects, etc. depending on your discipline) for each *variable* for each unit of each level at which that slope is permitted to vary.

It's a citation from epidemiology, not economics, but it is *well written* as an introduction to these kinds of models (including the "why would we care" bits): Duncan, C., Jones, K., and Moon, G. (1998). [Context, composition and heterogeneity: Using multilevel models in health research](http://www.academia.edu/download/30336415/duncanjonesmoon1998.pdf). *Social Science & Medicine*, 46(1):97–117.

Comment: Ok, so it seems to be a linguistic thing then, because both you and M.Mayer seem to argue that random effect is a family of estimator including random intercept and random slope models. Whereas in economics random effects implies random intercept.
The only difference between the two stata commands I wrote up seems to be that once uses MLE and the other some least squares version.

Comment: Your second specification is generalized least squares (GLS).

Comment: I'd have said exactly as Alexis and Michael Mayer did - that a random intercept model is a special case of a random effects model.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov This is a late to the party response, but my answer was about the model, not the estimator: could be estimated using GLS, IGLS, MCMC/Bayesian, etc. Right? Or is differentiating model from estimator not the way folks should use their statistical concepts?