# Linear regression when observations may not be independent

Tags: regression, mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures

I conducted an experiments where each participants played 5 rounds. For each round and for each participant I collected information regarding the dependent variable $y$ and the independent variables $X$.

Using linear regression to understand how $X$ drives $y$ I was wondering if any of the two below approaches are considered to be **better** from a methodological or statistical stand points:

1. Mean approach: for each participant calculate the mean of $y$ and $X$ and run a regression on the reduced dataset (reduced by factor 5, i.e. the rounds).
2. Rounds approach: use the raw data and include as control variable the round number.

Given that approach 2 has more observations and I don't average out anything I prefer to do approach 2. However, the observations are not independent using this approach so I was wondering if I can do this?

I would be grateful for some insight on

a. if the approaches both are correct / can be applied or if there are any flaws.

b. what other "typical" methods there are to analyse this kind of data (anova, panel regression?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hidden option C is best: use a [mixed-model](/questions/tagged/mixed-model) to model *all* your data at the same time while accounting for the non-independence using a random effect for participant.

Here's are some threads explaining how these work:

[What is the difference between fixed effect, random effect and mixed effect models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode)

[What is a difference between random effects-, fixed effects- and marginal model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/what-is-a-difference-between-random-effects-fixed-effects-and-marginal-model)

[Concepts behind fixed/random effects models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33984/concepts-behind-fixed-random-effects-models)

[Are mixed models useful as predictive models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250277/are-mixed-models-useful-as-predictive-models)

Comment: Great, thanks for the swift support and the useful links!

Comment: Worth noting that this is similar to including **participant ID** (not round number) as a control variable in OP's approach #2.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should have included "person" not "round". But is this than actually similar to the above mixed models? Or is this something completely different (less good method)?

Comment: @FredMaster Happy to help. To your last comment, mixed models take advantage of 'partial pooling' and generally perform better than simply including person as a fixed effect (the normal kind) in a standard regression. See the linked threads to understand partial pooling better. Also this one, which is less detailed but perhaps a bit easier to follow: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250277/are-mixed-models-useful-as-predictive-models

Comment: @FredMaster in case you're completely new to the world of mixed-effects modelling, I recommend [McElreath's gentle introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwVqiiXYeC4&list=PLDcUM9US4XdPz-KxHM4XHt7uUVGWWVSus&index=12).