# Conditional logistic regression vs GLMM in R

Tags: r, logistic, glmm, clogit

I have paired data (GWAS case/control study) and I have heard using conditional logistic regression or generalized linear mixed models (GLMM) is appropriate. Which should I use in this case? Why would you use one over the other. More importantly can you guys point me towards resources for doing these methods in `R`? I'm finding a lot of material for `SAS`, which I do not prefer. I can provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The conditional logistic regression applies fixed effects (in the
  context of econometrics),

  $$ logit(p_{ij})=\boldsymbol x_{ij}^{'}\boldsymbol\beta+u_i.$$
  where each pair of subjects has an individual intercept ($u_i$). It can be implemented  with `clogit()` of package `survival` or `clogistic()` of package `Epi`.
- Generalized linear mixed models (GLMM) for binary data can adopt link
  functions like `logit`, `probit` and `cloglog`. The mixed logistic
  regression is as,

  $$ logit(p_{ij})=\boldsymbol x_{ij}^{'}\boldsymbol\beta+\boldsymbol
     z_{ij}^{'}\boldsymbol u_i$$
  where $\boldsymbol u_i$ are random variables and can have the distribution assumption (e.g. normal distribution). Of course you can use a random intercept model, i.e. $\boldsymbol z_{ij}^{'}=1$ and $\boldsymbol u_i$ is a scalar. You can estimate GLMM using `glmer()` of package `lme4`.
- As to the choice between conditional logistic regression and GLMM for binary data,
  some people are in favor of conditonal (fixed-effects) logistic regression and GLMM with `probit` link, but against fixed-effects `probit` or GLMM with `logit` link. The reason may be that some of the consistency properties break down, especially with small within-cluster sample size ($n_i=2$ for your case).

  You can find the clarification of fixed effects and random effects (and marginal models) in
  different contexts [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/what-is-a-difference-between-random-effects-fixed-effects-and-marginal-model/68753#68753).

Comment: how can case-control even be analyzed with GLMM ? isn't one assumption is that observations are independent conditioned on the strata? Case-Controls destroys this assumption...