# What is the consequence of not measuring time as a random effect in an MLA?

Tags: random-variable, multilevel-analysis, model, mixed-random-variable

I'm conducting a multilevel regression analysis (mixed model) with time as the levels.

My teacher wanted me to measure time as both a fixed and as a random effect. However, it turned out I couldn't measure time as a random effect because of convergence issues, so it's now only being measured as a fixed effect.

Could someone please explain to me what the consequence is of not measuring time as a random effect? Please use simple language as I'm not a native English speaker and very bad at statistics.

Comment: [Can a variable be included in a mixed model as a fixed effect and as a random effect at the same time?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71587/can-a-variable-be-included-in-a-mixed-model-as-a-fixed-effect-and-as-a-random-ef)