# Longitudinal data: baseline effect versus random intercept 2

Tags: time-series, panel-data, random-effects-model

My question follows this post: [Longitudinal data: baseline effect versus random intercept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118207/longitudinal-data-baseline-effect-versus-random-intercept?newsletter=1&nlcode=254556%7c00c9)

The topic is very interesting and I have two further questions, one very practical and another about modelling.

Q1 : I assume user7064 is computing the model with R. How such a case can be specified with the lm function? I have the impression it looks like an addition of two linear models, one with t0 and another with tj, but how to do this simultaneously?

Q2 : Can we imagine the same procedure with a baseline constituted of several observations? (eg. not just t0, but t-1, ..., t-x)

Thanks to all!