What is the difference between a) multilevel modelling and b) adding a categorical IV to a multiple regression?
The examples of multilevel modelling I have seen are equivalent to treating the group as an extra categorical IV in a multiple regression. For example, if children are grouped into N classes, you could add 'class' as an extra IV, and then dummy code that into N-1 binary variables to run the actual regression.
I'm sure there's more to multilevel modelling than this -- there are whole books on it, and reams more about fixed and random and mixed effects. What am I missing, please?

Look at the mixed model tag that I just added to your question. These are good places to start: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/what-is-a-difference-between-random-effects-fixed-effects-and-marginal-model and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-in-mixed-effect-model

Do see the tag @mkt added, But, very briefly, MLM involves cases where there are dependent errors. They are not the same as adding a categorical IV, as that does not deal with this violation.

The dummy variable approach you mention is equivalent to a "fixed effects" model. See the links that @mkt posted for much more detail.

Let's say you have a dataset of children grouped into classes. One way to analyze these data is to treat "class" as just another (categorical) independent variable - as a characteristic of the students. So students have an age, a race, and a class.
If instead you wanted to analyze these data through multilevel modeling, you would think about class not as another variable but another type of observation. In this way of thinking, it is not that students "have" a class the same way they have a race, but that there are two kinds of entities in your dataset: students, and classes. These two kinds of observations are at different "levels" of analysis: student observations are "nested" within class observations (hence the "multilevel" name). The next move is basically to assume that, just like we assume that students have an "error term" that varies normally around some value, classes have their own class-level normal error term, that varies in the same way. Some people (but not Bayesians) call this treating class as a "random effect" (vs the "fixed effect" approach of estimating a variable with a coefficient). The phrase "mixed effects" comes from the fact that these models usually have a "mix" of random and fixed effects.
That is the basic conceptual move behind treating these data as multileveled. You don't HAVE to analyze these data as multileveled, but these two different approaches have very different practical implications. Here are some of those implications (greatly simplified).

If you treat class as variable then you can't analyze any other variables that denote characteristics of the class ("class level variables") like "class size" or "teacher quality." Those variables will be perfectly colinear to the class dummies and will drop out of the model. So if you want to know what types of classes are associated with good or bad student outcomes, then treating class as a variable doesn't work.

But if you don't include class as a variable then you are probably violating a whole bunch of assumptions for OLS or whatever model type you are using because individual students observations are going to be correlated within classes. Treating class as a random effect can help to address those violations and keep you from getting incorrect coefficients and standard errors. But there are also other ways (like cluster robust standard errors) to deal with these issues.

When you treat class as a random effect (and thereby run a multilevel model) you won't get a "coefficient" for class - there will be nothing telling you how class is associated with the DV, because you are not thinking about class as a variable at all. What you will get instead is an estimates of the variance or standard deviation of the class level error term, which can be used for various purposes. On the other hand, you will be able to see the effects of class level variables.

By including class as a random effect you can do a bunch of other cool things that are often useful. You can "decompose" the variance of the dependent variable to see how much of it is due to "student level" vs "class level" factors. You can use Bayesian methods to "borrow" some information from bigger classes to improve estimation for smaller classes. The list goes on.


That's the basic idea...all of those books about multilevel modeling you mention discuss these issues and more in much greater detail.

On 2, why would a fixed effect not be enough to remove the correlation?

Including "class" as a fixed effect (a set of dummy variables) would be enough to fix the violations of OLS assumptions. But (per #1) it also removes your ability to analyze class level variables. If all you want to do is "control for bias at the class level" then treating class as a variable is a fine approach (although it can be statistically inefficient in some cases). But there are other questions you might want to ask (like "are bigger classes better?") where that approach won't work, and you might need to explore treating class as a "random effect," and running a multilevel model.

In the situation you describe, with a single grouping variable, practically speaking it can indeed be effectively the same when the grouping variable enters the model as a fixed effect (independent variable), and when it enters the model as a random effect (random intercepts).
However, conceptually, the models are quite different. A few points concerning the decision to model a factor as random or fixed:

If you are specifically interested in the association between the grouping factor and the response, then you would fit the variable as a fixed effect.

Often you would use a multilevel model when there is a clear hierarchy, particularly when there are two grouping variables (eg students and schools), and especially when there is interest in understanding the variation in the response as it relates to the separate levels, for instance when you want to compute a Variation Partition Coefficient or an Intra-Class Correlation coefficient.

when the levels of the factor observed can be thought of as coming from a larger population, random is a good choice.

when there are very many levels, say 20+, it is more parsimonious to treat the factor as random, otherwise you will have 19+ fixed effects for the factor to interpret, and you may lose degrees of freedom if you treat it as fixed.

Conversely, when there are very few levels observed, say 3-4, then it makes much more sense to fit the grouping variable as fixed, since it will be hard to estimate a robust variance for the random intercepts with so few levels.

when you fit a model with random intercepts and the random effects are very far from being normally distributed, a fixed effects model would make more sense, since normality of the random effects is an assumption of many implementations of multilevel modelling (also known as mixed effects modelling).

when you fit a model with random intercepts, so that each subject has their own intercept for a fixed effect, it often also makes sense to allow subjects to have their own slope too, by adding random slopes (technically it is possible to treat the grouping factor as fixed and also have random slopes, but this is a rare situation).

when you have serial correlation among the observations, a multilevel/mixed effects model is able to handle the autocorrelation by either fitting random slopes for a time variable, or specifying a correlation structure for the unit level residuals. Many software implementations allow the flexible specification of such a structure, eg AR(1), Toeplitz, Ante-dependence - see my answer here for further details about this: Beyond AR(1) as a covariance structure for mixed models with repeated measures


